# app crash in the dealloc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, memory

My app crashes in `dealloc`, but only sometimes.

I create one array for caching 5 objects. When the user taps right or left one, a new object is added and the last is removed. When I tested the app, after tapping the right or left button 100-500 times, the app crashes.

The app crashes in the `dealloc` method but all objects are allocated and released correctly.

My `dealloc` method :

```
 - (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [_sImageLane release];
    [_sTipoLane release];
    [_maRecomended release];
    [_maProdcucts release]; // here crash in this line EXC_BAD_ACCESSE
}
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put `[super dealloc]` last instead of first.

**EDIT** : The reason why this happens is due to the lifecycle of an objc object.  When it is time for it to die, the object is sent the `dealloc` message.  Inside that method, the object must clean itself up, and pass the message up the inheritance chain (because the super class needs to clean itself up as well).  Well, what happens if you do that correctly with `[super dealloc]` being last?

> Clean up resources on self -> clean up resources on super -> clean up resources on super's super -> etc -> memory reclaimed by runtime.

Nice, well what happens if you do it your way?

> Clean up resources on super -> clean up resources on super's super -> etc. -> memory reclaimed by runtime -> clean up resources on self

Oops, now you are accessing reclaimed memory and trying to interact with it (i.e. EXC_BAD_ACCESS or worse, messing with memory somewhere else on another object and not realizing it).

`NSObject`'s dealloc method literally frees the memory (probably via `free()`) so once you've called that you are in undefined dangerous gray areas.

Comment: Thanks @borrden I'm gonna prove that, I will notice you.

Comment: Mother of god yea this solves my issue thanks @borrden but why? why call de super last? thanks

Comment: Awesome answer. +1 for When it is time for it to die :D

Answer (score 0):

What version of Xcode are you using? New versions don't require you to allocate or release memory. It does it for you come runtime. Try commenting out the dealloc method, and compile.

Comment: If the OP isn't using ARC, commenting out the `[super dealloc]` will probably fix the crash but will cause a memory leak instead.  I suspect @borrrden has the correct answer.

Comment: Not entirely true. You have to explicitly enable ARC. New projects created on new versions of XCode have it on by default, but older projects must enable it.

Comment: @mttrb This code will not even compile under ARC ([super dealloc] is a compiler error).  That is a big clue that ARC is not being used :).  Also commenting out [super dealloc] on non-ARC will cause a compiler warning IIRC.

Comment: @borrrden Yeah, I realised it wouldn't actually compile under ARC. My comment was more about commenting out the `[super dealloc]` in non-ARC code "fixing" the problem. I probably should have said "__As__ the OP isn't using ARC..."